# Removing Key Press Delay

Tags: c, gtk

I'm writing a game in C using the Gtk libraries, in which the player controls a movable character. However, I want the player to be able to hold a key to continuously move in one direction. How do I override the normal behavior for holding a key, in which a key event is generated, there is a brief pause, and then key events occur in a continuous stream?

I've noticed a similar question was asked previously about doing the same thing in Javascript; however, the answer doesn't really assist with implementing the same system in Gtk. I've noticed that there is a GtkDevice "class"; is there a function having to do with it that will allow me to control the buffering of keyboard input?

Comment: The delay/repeat behaviour is probably being controlled by your operating system, not by your application.  You could write your own support by tracking key down/key up events directly.

Comment: Are you sure GTK is the best tool for writing a game? I'd suggest using a specialized game toolkit, that will provide these kinds of facilities automatically.

Comment: I wanted to learn GUIs in C anyway for future use, and the game is simple enough that I don't need to use a special toolkit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connect to GTK's `key_press_event` and `key_release_event` signals.

They will work as you describe.

It will be your responsibility to track whether the keys you are interested in are currently pressed at a given time.

Comment: I was able to think of a way to work around it, using gtk_key_snooper_install(), before you commented. I don't have enough reputation to answer my own question until 8 hours have passed since I asked the question, but tomorrow I'll post my solution. But thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Indeed, you need to be tracking key press/release events, NOT character-generation events or similar.

Comment: Yeah, my solution does exactly what you're suggesting. Thanks for the assistance.